# How to set a default value in a meta box

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I found a post for adding units of measure after a price in woocomerce sites. It works wonderfully for me.
[Adding unit amount after WooCommerce price.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/103469/adding-unit-ammount-after-woocommerce-price-example-24-m2-and-24-m/125052#125052)

I want to add a default value since 95% of my products are all sq ft. Im hoping this will make it so all products show sq ft, but the few products I change to new values will have the new value displayed.

**Edit**
Here is what I ended up using to accomplish this.

```
//add default of sq sf
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html','wpse103469_add_price_per_unit_meta_default');
function wpse103469_add_price_per_unit_meta_default( $price ) {
 $default_units =  __( 'sq. ft.', 'myplugin_textdomain' );
 $units = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'wc_price_per_unit_key', true );
 return ( $units ) ? $price .= ' ' . $units : $price .= ' ' . $default_units;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a tweaked version of the referenced `wpse103469_add_price_per_unit_meta_to_price()` function. If no units have been specified, the default units are appended to the price, otherwise the user-specified units are used.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html', 'wpse103469_add_price_per_unit_meta_to_price');
function wpse103469_add_price_per_unit_meta_to_price( $price ) {
     $default_units =  __( 'sq. ft.', 'myplugin_textdomain' );
     $units = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'wc_price_per_unit_key', true );

     return ( $units ) ? $price .= ' ' . $units : $price .= ' ' . $default_units;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. After a slight edit, I was able to make that work.

Comment: Glad that worked, and welcome to WPSE! Can you please click the accept button if you feel that this solution solved your issue?